# Display webpage on desktop background (WinXP)

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, desktop-customization

I want to display a website on the desktop background imitating the functionality of Active Desktop (I decided against using it because it is really limited). Here's what I'm looking for:

- It should allow pop-up windows (Ave's DesktopSites and Snippage don't)
- Be very minimal (like WallpaperWebPage, but it's core browser IE messes up most websites)
- Accept flash and java, if possible. Something that renders pages using Webkit would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

To set a Web page as your desktop wallpaper, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, point to Settings, click Control Panel, and then double-click Display.
2. On the Background tab, click Browse.
3. In the Files Of Type box, click Background Files.
4. Click the .htm file you want to use as the background, and then click Open.
5. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when we need to visit a webpage frequently. Web pages that inform about score updates of a game and stock rates for a company are good examples. To keep up with it all, we need to open the browser every time we wish to take the glance at the updates. In order to negate this repetitive effort, let us see how to view a live web page as your desktop background in Windows XP.

Adding A Webpage URL as Background:

1. Right-click on your Desktop. Click Properties. Doing so, the Display Properties dialog box opens.
2. Go to Desktop Tab. Click the Customize Desktop… button at the bottom of the dialog box.
3. Another dialog box Desktop Items opens. Go to the Web Tab. Press New at the right of the dialog box.
4. In the resulting box, find and enter the URL of the webpage you want to show as your desktop background. Press OK.

http://www.worldstart.com/web-page-background-in-windows-xp/